# how i can run this insertion sort code in java?

Tags: java

```
public class NIS {

    public static void insertSort(int[] A)
    {
          for(int i = 1; i < A.length; i++)
          {
            int value = A[i];
            int j = i - 1;
            while(j >= 0 && A[j] > value)
            {
              A[j + 1] = A[j];
              j = j - 1;
            }
            A[j + 1] = value;
          }
        }
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int a[]={20,10,2,100,1};
        insertSort(a);
        for (int i=0 ; i <a.length ; i++)
        {
            System.out.println(" "+a[i]);
        }

 // in this code there are many problems if anyone of you can help me so plz debugg this code.
    }

}
```

Comment: You can run it like this:  1) `javac -cp . NIS.java`  2) `java NIS`

Comment: Please take a look at this url before asking any question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! “Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.” Quoted from [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: I frankly don’t see any problems in your code. Well, one, maybe: variable and parameter names in Java conventionally begin with a small letter, so you should rename the parameter to `insertSort()` to `a`, like in `main()` (no issue in using the same name in both places). Your IDE can perform the rename for you.

Comment: You will probably want to run it in the IDE you have typed it in? The answer to how to run it depends on which IDE you are using, like IntelliJ IDEA or Eclipse or BlueJ or Netbeans, for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran your code and it works very well. Just to make sure, I ran it on randomly generated lists of size 20 with integers ranging from the maximum integer size to the minimum integer size, and each one worked fine. It doesn't even break for arrays of size 1 or 0, which is a lot more that can be said for a lot of homemade sorting algorithms. Good job, and happy coding!